# Ubuntu lock screen will not open

Tags: 13.04, lock-screen

Many times when the screen has automatically locked and I type the password, the message just reappears. I can continue to enter the password, but the message just pops up again. In order to log in I have to hit the "change user" button and login using that screen instead.

After I have logged in I get a crash report that wont load much information.

I am using Ubuntu 13.04.

anyone have an idea as to how I can make the screen work?

**Update:** *It looks like the problem could be related to Google Chrome somehow, I allays have that program running the the problem occurs.*

[image]

**Update (01.10.2013):** This is still an issue

Comment: Try re-installing gnome screensaver. `sudo apt-get install --reinstall gnome-screensaver`

Comment: That did not seem to work, when I lock the screen I still get the same repeated lock screen.

Comment: it's not going to *change* anything, just re-install the current one. Does the problem persist after that?

Comment: yeah, I know, it's what I mean, I locked the screen after re-install and got the repeated lock again, had to use the change user button to get back in.

Comment: You might need to restart the computer for the re-install to take affect.

Comment: A restart did not help

Comment: Check in terminal what is the result of: `gsettings get org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-display-ac`

Comment: @RaduRădeanu 1800

Comment: **Update (01.10.2013):** This is still an issue